# Change textbox value based on select option value dynamically

Tags: javascript, php

I have a table that populated with mysql data. I want to change the textbox value based on the value of the drop down. What I've done is only the first row changes its value but the following row doesn't work.
Below is my code.

```
//this is inside while loop
<input type='text' name='qqty[]' value='<?php echo $avail; ?>' id="avail" class='form-control1' readonly = 'readonly'>

<select class="form-control1" name="qty[]" id="sType"  onChange="check();">
        <option value="<?php echo $avail;?>"><?php echo $Uconv;?></option>
        <option value="<?php echo $qty;?>"><?php echo $uom;?></option>
</select>

//my javascript code
<script>
function check() {
   document.getElementById("avail").value = document.getElementById("sType").value;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to give individual ids to each input, and then find it. Let's say your iteration variable is `$i`:

```
<?php
  $i=1;
  while (your_condition) {
?>
    <input type='text' name='qqty[]' value='<?php echo $avail; ?>' id="avail<?= $i ?>" class='form-control1' readonly = 'readonly'>

    <select class="form-control1" name="qty[]" id="sType"  onChange="check('<?= $i ?>');">
            <option value="<?php echo $avail;?>"><?php echo $Uconv;?></option>
            <option value="<?php echo $qty;?>"><?php echo $uom;?></option>
    </select>

    //my javascript code
    <script>
    function check(i) {
       document.getElementById("avail"+i).value = document.getElementById("sType").value;
    }
    </script>
<?php
$i++;
} // end while
?>
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks! How to assign the value of $i? I'm using while loop on fetching the data on mysql database.

Answer (score 0):

If you have that code inside a loop, you have multiple elements with the same id (`avail` and such). When you do `getElementById` it will return only the first element with that id, AKA, the first row.

You should add unique ids to each element, let's say, by adding an increasing integer inside the loop, like this:

```
<?php
for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
    ?>
        <input type='text' name='qqty[]' value='<?php echo $avail; ?>' id="avail_<?php echo $x; ?>" class='form-control1' readonly = 'readonly'>
        <select class="form-control1" name="qty[]" id="sType_<?php echo $x; ?>"  onChange="check('<?php echo $x; ?>');">
            <option value="<?php echo $avail;?>"><?php echo $Uconv;?></option>
            <option value="<?php echo $qty;?>"><?php echo $uom;?></option>
        </select>
    <?php
}
?>
<script>
function check(i) {
    document.getElementById("avail_"+i).value = document.getElementById("sType_"+i).value;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
<select onchange="ChooseContact(this)">
    <option value='1'>1</option>
    <option value='2'>2</option>
</select>

<input id="friendName">

function ChooseContact(data) {

    document.getElementById ("friendName").value = data.value;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are referencing the first row elements by id.
You need to change the id for each row and based on which row you edit change the values.